# Filter reponses by initial survey response

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that needs to be filtered by other responses within the same table. I use the following script which works but when there are duplicates of the 'Customer.customer_id' (which at times there are) the results are skewed. My question is whether there is a better way to rewrite this code to avoid this so it only selects distinct results from the 'Customer' table?

The example table below should return only '**Two**' responses as there are duplicate entries for customer_id '10' ( Based on query below)

Sample table:

```
[res_id]  [question_id]  [customer_id]  [survey_id]  [res_answer]
  1            20             10           155          male
  1            20             11           155          male
  1            20             10           155          male
  1            20             12           155          female
```

Current query:

```
  SELECT
  Responses.res_id AS responseID
     ,Responses.res_col AS answer
    ,Responses.res_created AS dateCreated
    ,Responses.res_notes AS note
    ,Responses.question_id AS questionID
    ,Responses.customer_id AS customerID
    ,Responses.res_answer AS subQuestion
    ,Responses.survey_id AS surveyID
    ,Responses.res_void AS void
    ,Customer.res_answer AS filter
FROM
    Responses, Responses AS Customer
WHERE
    rs.customer_id = Customer.customer_id
AND
    Responses.survey_id ='155' 
AND
    Customer.survey_id = '155'
AND
    Responses.question_id = '20'                    

AND CAST(Customer.res_answer AS VARCHAR(500)) = 'male'
AND Responses.res_void = '0'
```

Comment: Please edit your question tags to include the dbms and version you are using

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals [tag:tsql] makes it kind of obvious.

Comment: **(1)** Am I right to assume that your platform is MS SQL Server?  **(2)** In you sample I do not understand why you believe that it should be **2** rows.  Shouldn't be **3** rows? **(3)** You're doing `LEFT JOIN` and then effectively converting it to `INNER JOIN` with your `WHERE rs.customer_id = Customer.customer_id`. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Does your table have a primary key column?

Comment: Sorry left some test code in there, the wasn't meant to be a 'Left join' statement. The results table is queried to get the average and counts f or various responses.

Answer (score 0):

If Distinct is not supported in 2005 then group by

```
SELECT Distinct 
     Responses.res_id AS responseID
    ,Responses.res_col AS answer
    ,Responses.res_created AS dateCreated
    ,Responses.res_notes AS note
    ,Responses.question_id AS questionID
    ,Responses.customer_id AS customerID
    ,Responses.res_answer AS subQuestion
    ,Responses.survey_id AS surveyID
    ,Responses.res_void AS void
    ,'male'
FROM Responses
WHERE Responses.survey_id ='155' 
  AND Responses.question_id = '20'  
  AND Responses.res_void = '0'                  
  AND exists (select 1 from Responses c 
              where c.res_answer = 'male' 
                and c.survey_id  = '155'
                and c.ID = Responses.ID)
```

Comment: Not sure that grouping by is an option as there are some questions that may have multiple responses, the query in the original post falls down when the Customer.customer_id is checked against the main response table.

Comment: Does the current query work?  What makes you think group by is not and option?  That is why Customer.customer_id was removed.

Comment: Yes the current query does work only that when you have a situation where there is repeated data as in the table above the tally for all 'male' and their responses  would return a tally of 3 instead of 2. We have a survey of around 50 questions with different types of responses and we normally filter the total responses by gender or age group (multiple responses per question)